# Use toHaveBeenCalledWith to check EventTarget

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've built a custom `Input` React component (think wrapper) that renders an `HTML` input element.  When a value is entered the change is passed to the parent component like this:

```
const handleChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  setCurrentValue(event.target.value);
  props.onChange(event);
};
```

Everything works as expected but now I want to write a test for it:

```
it('Should render a Text Input', () => {
  const onChange = jest.fn();

  const { queryByTestId } = renderDom(
    <Input type={InputTypesEnum.TEXT} name='car' onChange={onChange} />
  );

  const textInput = queryByTestId('text-input');
  expect(textInput).toBeTruthy();

  const event = fireEvent.change(textInput, { target: { value: 'Ford' }});
  expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

This works fine too except that I want to add a final `expect` using `toHaveBeenCalledWith`. I've tried several things but can't figure out how to do it.  Any ideas?

**Update**: I've been reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling. It appears that if I change `handleChange` like this:

```
const handleChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<EventTarget>) => {
  event.persist();
  setCurrentValue(event.target.value);
  props.onChange(event);
};
```

then the received object from `onChange` does change to include my test data.  That said, I don't like the idea of altering an important feature of production code (in this case, event pooling) simply to accommodate a test.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I've tried several things"? Post the code for your attempts please.

Comment: I've erased that code now but I figured I needed to instantiate an instance of `SyntheticInputEvent` and then inject the name `car` and the value `Ford` into the object's `eventTarget` property.  Tried several approaches but none worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`

```
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      target: expect.objectContaining({
        value: "Ford"
      })
    })
  );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.